# extracting pieces of log file to push to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

if I have a log file such as the one below, how can I take advantage of `logstash` to extract pieces of information I need and push that into ES?

```
test_web_events.py: START: Mon Apr 27 13:35:25 2015
# TESTCASE TestWebPost ==================================================
# START TEST METHOD #################################: test_10_post_valid_json
[2015-04-27T13:35:25.657887] HTTP DELETE http://pppdc3mu.net:8080/rastplatz/v1/sink/db?k0=bradford4
{}
HTTP response: 200
0
POSTING event_id b29b6c7c-48cd-4cd9-b3c4-aa0a7edc1f35 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 13678af1-3e3a-4a6e-a61c-404eb94b9768 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 47b70306-2e7c-4cb2-9e75-5755d8d101d4 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 6599cdb2-0630-470d-879d-1130cf70c605 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id d088ce29-fa0d-4f45-b628-045dba1fd045 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 07d14813-b561-442c-9b86-dc40d1fcc721 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id b6aea24a-5424-4a0f-aac6-8cbaecc410db to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 016386bd-eac5-4f1c-8afc-a66326d37ddb to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 6610485d-71af-4dfa-9268-54be5408a793 to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
POSTING event_id 92786434-02f7-4248-a77b-bdd9d33b57be to ctg-business
Content-Type: text/plain
Posted 10 events
# END TEST METHOD ###################################: test_10_post_valid_json
test_web_events.py: FINISH: Mon Apr 27 13:35:36 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the multiline filter to join everything up to one event, and roll it into Elasticsearch.

You can grok{} and otherwise filter it on the way through, too.

Comment: I have this log file: http://dpaste.com/3FE2VNY I only want to extract certain pieces of information such as date time, and number of events posted. My attempt of putting this into elasticsearch results in hanging of logstash

Comment: If you have paid support, use it.  Otherwise, jump on the #logstash IRC channel for more real-time help.